# Coredata NSFetchRequest DictionaryResultType null properties Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Hello guys i am using this code to fetch the Result from Coredata

```
  func getRequest(entiryDesc:NSEntityDescription) -> NSFetchRequest{

    var request:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    request.entity = entiryDesc
    request.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType
    return request

}
```

Now the problem is i need All the attributes which contains the Nil value too but the excutefetchrequest returns only those properties which have values , is there any work around for this to return Null attributes with String like "" every time i fetch ? Thanks Advanced

Answer (score 4):

Of course, you can just dispense with the `.DictionaryResultType` and fetch normal managed objects. There are very few cases where the dictionary result type makes sense.

If you want to construct a dictionary with all attributes filled out (for whatever opaque reason), remember two things:

- Make sure to insert the null values as objects `NSNull()`
- You can use the `NSEntityDescription` API to generate all the attribute keys. Use `entityDescription.propertiesByName.allKeys` to generate a list of all attribute names of your entity.

Comment: i know with Object form i can get the Result with Null Attributes but i need to achieve this with .DictionaryResultType with out being overhead to converting the NSMangedObject to Dictionary at the end . but thanks for the help Mate

Comment: If you are anyway retrieving all attributes, there is no additional "overhead" if you get the managed object.